# AJAX update not passing proper parameters to SQL call in different environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, reactjs, http

***Issue***

So I'm using AJAX to update an organization with `name` and `phone` as the attributes. The update is working fine locally, but not on production.

***Data***

The logs I get locally:

```
Started PUT "/organizations/14" for ::1 at 2017-08-11 08:03:18 -0700
Processing by OrganizationsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"organization"=>{"name"=>"Org Name", "phone"=>"3434234322"}, "id"=>"14"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 195], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Organization Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."user_id" = 195 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (9.2ms)  UPDATE "organizations" SET "phone" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "organizations"."id" = $3  [["phone", "3434234322"], ["updated_at", 2017-08-11 15:03:18 UTC], ["id", 14]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)
```

The logs I get on production:

```
Started PUT "/organizations/1" for [censored] at 2017-08-11 15:12:58 +0000 
Processing by OrganizationsController#update as JSON 
  Parameters: {"organization"=>{"name"=>"Org Name", "phone"=>"12121212"}, "id"=>"1"} 
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 48], ["LIMIT", 1]] 
  Organization Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."user_id" = 48 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]] 
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN 
  SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "organizations" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "organizations"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", 2017-08-11 15:12:58 UTC], ["id", 1]] 
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT 
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.9ms)
```

***My Thoughts***

So it seems the difference here is the SQL call (line 7). Locally, phone is properly passed in, like so:

`SQL (9.2ms)  UPDATE "organizations" SET "phone" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "organizations"."id" = $3  [["phone", "3434234322"], ["updated_at", 2017-08-11 15:03:18 UTC], ["id", 14]]`

But on production, it's not...

`SQL (0.9ms)  UPDATE "organizations" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "organizations"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", 2017-08-11 15:12:58 UTC], ["id", 1]]`

I can't figure out why this would be working locally, but not on production. It's also worth noting that if I do an AJAX update for `name`, it works in both environments. I added `phone` to the database recently, and this particular organization didn't have `phone` as an attribute when it was created, so I thought that might have something to do with it. But I can see the attribute in the database, and can assign it a value and save without any issues. Unless I'm mistaken, this is exactly what I'm trying to do when I pass it to the controller.

***Relevant code***

My AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/organizations/${organization.id}`,
    method: 'PUT',
    data: { "organization": {
        "name": nameValue,
        "phone": phoneValue
    }},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

And my controller (Rails):

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_organization, only: [:edit, :update]
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def edit
    end

    def update
        respond_to do |format|
            if @organization.update(organization_params)
                format.html { redirect_to '/dashboard', notice: 'Organization was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render json: @organization }
            else
                format.html { render '/dashboard' }
                format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end

    private
    def set_organization
        @organization = Organization.find_by(user: current_user)
    end

    def organization_params
        params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :phone)
    end

end
```

I only added the AJAX call above because I'm sure that's all that's needed. But for the sake of completeness, here is more of the React component it's used in:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class OrganizationInput extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nameValue: this.props.organization.name,
            phoneValue: this.props.organization.phone,
            xhr: false,
            faClass: null,
        }
    }

    handleInput =(event, input)=> {
        this.setState({[input]: event.target.value

            // creates font awesome spinner
            this.handleFaChange() 

            const { organization } = this.props
            const { nameValue, phoneValue } = this.state

            if(this.state.xhr !== false) {clearTimeout(this.state.xhr)}

            this.state.xhr = setTimeout(() => {
                $.ajax({
                    url: `/organizations/${organization.id}`,
                    method: 'PUT',
                    data: { "organization": {
                        "name": nameValue,
                        "phone": phoneValue
                    }},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: (data) => {
                        this.setState({xhr: false})

                        // creates font awesome check mark
                        this.handleFaChange()
                    }
                });
            }, 300)
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { organization } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.state.nameValue} className="organization-input" placeholder={`Barbershop Name`} onChange={(e)=> {this.handleInput(e, "nameValue")}}/>
                <input value={this.state.phoneValue} className="organization-input" placeholder={`Phone Number`} onChange={(e)=> {this.handleInput(e, "phoneValue")}}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did the application get restarted after the `phone` attribute was added to the `organizations` table?

Also, you may want to change `if @organization.update(organization_params)` to `if @organization.update!(organization_params)` so an exception will be raised if there's a validation failure.

Comment: Yup it was restarted. Didn't do anything. Thanks for the tip on the update call. I did figure out a solution, though (kind of). Simply wouldn't update any organizations that were created before the addition of the phone attribute and its corresponding migration. I just wrote a quick script to clone all the  organizations that were previously in the database and reassigned all associations to those organizations. It's a workaround that fixes the issue for me, but I'm still curious why I had to do this. I could update the organizations from the console, but not directly from the application.

Comment: It's as if the running application somehow isn't seeing that new field... but even that shouldn't be the issue since you restarted it.  That's a puzzler for sure.